# How to change installed ruby version

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am trying to run ruby on my RPi (Raspbian/Debian distro).
I have installed ruby with apt-get command, but it has installed 1.9. 3 version. I wanted newer one, so I removed that one and next, according to some guide, I have installed ruby-install and used it to install ruby 2.1. 5. After some downloading, compiling it has installed ruby to my ~/. Rubies/ruby-2.1. 5 directory.

My problem is that `ruby -v` still says `ruby 1.9.3`. I don't know why 1.9. 3 hasn't been fully uninstalled and why it hasn't been updated to the newer one. How can I properly configure my system to acknowledge my new ruby installation?

Comment: Look at using a tool like [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)...

Comment: Or [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io/rvm/install).

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102678/making-ruby-available-to-all-users/102684#102684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because jasonwryan hasn't posted an answer that I could check as the right one, I'm aswering my own question with his comment-answer. The `chruby` tool with it's autoswitcher worked great. Again thanks Jason.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your path in your `/home/$your_username/.bashrc` to include `/path/to/ruby-2.1.5/bin` like so:

```
export PATH="$HOME/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:${PATH}"
```

Do note that I put it *before* (aka "at the front" of) the existing path environment variable.  You can test this by executing the command `which ruby`.

["How does the path enviroment variable work in linux?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77898/37860) has more details.

Comment: this one didn't work for me, I've used chruby with it's autoswitcher

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of ruby version managers, and tools such as `rvm`, `chruby`, `rbenv` and so on.

You may check the whole list of them at
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management